# SSRS 3.0 CDate Format

Tags: reporting-services

Would someone be kind enough to provide an example of how to turn a date field presenting in SQL as *YYYYMMDD* into a date in SSRS 3.0?  I've tried this already and get an #ERROR response in my Report Runs.

> `Format(CDate(Left$(!Field,4) & "/" & Mid$(!Field,5,2) & "/" & Right$(!Field,2)),"mm/dd/yyyy")`

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Youa re formatting a DateTiem to another DatetIme format?

Try these:

```
=Format(Fields!myDate.Value, “M/d/yy”) - 2/11/08
=Format(Fields!myDate.Value, “MM/dd/yyyy”) - 02/11/2008
=Format(Fields!myDate.Value, “d-MMMM-yy”) - 11-December-08
=Format(Fields!myDate.Value, “d-MMM-yyyy”) - 11-Dec-2008 =Format(Fields!myDate.Value, “M/d/yyyy H:mm”) - 2/11/2008 13:50
=Format(Fields!myDate.Value, “MMM-dd-yyyy”) - Feb-11-2008
```

Got this from [here](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2008/02/format-dates-in-ssrs-reports.html)